Why are volumes of revolution typically taught in Calculus 2 and not Calculus 3?
Solids of revolution are typically taught in Calculus II for most undergraduate students or in AP Calculus BC for most high school students. However, it seems to me that this topic is far more appropriate for Calculus III (Multivariable Calculus) than for Calculus II.
Using cylindrical coordinates (which are covered in Calculus III), one can easily find the volume of a solid of revolution about an axis through triple integration. For example, if a given solid of revolution is defined as being the solid generated after rotating the curve $r = f(z)$ from points $z = a$ to $z = b$, one can easily compute its volume by evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{0}^{f(z)}rdrdzd\theta$. This is a consequence of the more general idea that integrating volume elements (such as $rdrdzd\theta$) thrice gives the volume of a solid enclosed by the bounds of integration.
However, this problem is typically solved in single-variable calculus courses using the formula $\int_{a}^{b}\pi f(z)^2dz$. These formulae are equivalent, but the derivation is much less intuitive: it comes from the idea of "chopping" the solid into infinitely many 2D slices perpendicular to the z axis and adding the areas of infinitely many of these slices to calculate the volume. Adding to the confusion is that we students generally memorize this formula instead of understanding how this ties into using integration to find volumes more generally, which is what the approach using cylindrical coordinates does.
Worse still is the idea that there are two ways to think about solids of revolution that students are expected to know: the Disk Method (which was described above) and the Shell Method, which involves considering infinitely many radial slices around the z axis; students are expected to use both methods, and the relationship between the two is often not shown.
The Disk and Shell Methods might not be computationally harder than triple integration, but they are certainly conceptually harder, especially for people who have not been introduced to cylindrical coordinates. Plus, people in Calculus II or AP Calculus BC likely have very little experience with integrals, which makes the Disk and Shell Methods even less intuitive. The method used to compute volumes of revolution using triple integrals can be applied to any 3D object: just integrate the volume element within the bounds of integration; volumes of revolution are just the special case where $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. Solids of revolution are much more naturally thought of in terms of triple integrating volume elements in cylindrical coordinates than in terms of single integrating areas.
This should be a Calculus III topic, but it is most often taught in Calculus II (a course where students have not even been exposed to multiple integrals). Why is this?

It's in Calc 1 in our curriculum, and it's a single-variable problem, with no need to make it a multivariable problem. It shows an important application of integration, and application are important for developing conceptual understanding of integration. Describing the problem in cylindrical coordinates is red herring and makes the problem seem much more complicated to me.

Note that the Disk Method (as you described it) is simply an application of Fubini's theorem (i.e. deciding to integrate first in some direction), whereas your triple integral approach uses both Fubini's theorem and the change of variables at the same time. From this point of view, it's conceptually harder.

The course names seem to indicate that this is a question about courses in the United States, so I added the USA tag.

There are some STEM majors that require Calc 2 but not Calc 3.

Hi! I have a small request; would you consider replacing "Calculus II", "Calculus III" and "AP Calculus BC" with "Calculus II (~approximate student age)", "Calculus III (~approximate student age)", "AP Calculus BC (~approximate student age)", so that people who are not familiar with your country's particular naming scheme can still understand the rough meaning?

FWIW,  volumes of revolution was dropped from the High School A-level maths course in the 2017, and moved to the "Further Maths" A-level.  This applies to England and Wales (and other countries that use the English Exam System)

@stef In the US people start calculus as early as age 16 (maybe 15) and as late as age 19 (typically). Or more precisely, I get 18yo students some of whom have completed two years of calculus and some of whom need a preparatory course (or two) before starting calculus. Attaching each course to an age is problematic. Calc I, II, III (IV) are each half-year courses taken in sequence. Calc III is often called multivariable calculus or vector calculus; Calc IV is usually called differential equations. Some universities have three shorter terms and perhaps different names with different meanings.

@user1815 Awesome, thanks!

If you use the triple integral approach you also need to explain how to do a change of variable in multiple dimensions to get the polar coordinates and the extra r-factor. So fully understanding the formula from there seems at least as hard.

The questions that apply only to particular small regions of the world are discouraged on SE. Would you mind editing the question to remove the jargon used in your location, such as "Calculus II", "Calculus III" and "AP Calculus BC", and make it understandable to all users?

It's important to try to get students in a calculus course to appreciate the wide scope of applications of derivatives and integrals beyond the very specific first application they see.
Derivatives of single-variable functions are first introduced as slopes of tangent lines, but if that  was the only way derivatives are used then it wouldn't be necessary for so many students not specializing in math to learn about it. Derivatives can be applied in numerous ways that do not directly mention tangent lines thanks to the many different ways to interpret tangent line slopes: they tell us rates of changes in many physical settings (velocity, charge, population, ...), max/min problems, how functions increase/decrease, Newton's method to solve $f(x) = 0$, and so on.
Similarly, while integrals of single-variable functions are first introduced as areas under curves, they admit many other applications because the process of integration models many things that are not directly about the area under a curve: distance traveled (more generally, net change that allows functions with both positive and negative values), length, volume, work, escape velocity, pressure, probability, and so on. Integrals outside of a math class are often calculated with a computer, so learning how to  set up an integral in numerous applications is just as important as learning the fundamental theorem of calculus. It's particularly striking that integration is initially presented as a way to work out area, a 2-dimensional concept, but it turns out to be applicable to lengths and volumes, which are 1-dimensional and 3-dimensional concepts. This can seem at first to be counterintuitive, and I think coming to grips with how this is possible helps students get a better idea of the process of integration: the math doesn't know that an integral is supposed to be interpreted as an area, and indeed it can be interpreted in many other ways.
I am not advocating for teaching both the disc method and the shell method in Calculus 2 (my own preference is to focus in a course only on the disc method), but I think doing some application of integration to volumes is worthwhile to help students see that it's wrong to think "integral = area". Instead, "integral = a certain procedure based on multiplying and adding", and this turns out to be why integration is so widely applicable.
That the volume of a sphere can be worked out using the disc method makes it a fantastic example of the disc method, in my opinion, partly for its mathematical appeal but also for the history of this result going back to Archimedes.
I agree with another answer that it's worth remembering that not everyone in a single-variable calculus course is going to take multivariable calculus, so removing a topic from the single-variable course could mean certain students will just never see it at all. So even though single-variable integration won't help students determine all volumes of reasonable-looking solid bodies, the fact that it can let them determine some of thse volumes is a good enough reason for me to keep it as a topic in a single-variable calculus course (at least with the disc method).

I forgot about students in single-variable calculus who will not take multivariable calculus. (I am a undergraduate student, not an instructor.) I still think there are other ways to motivate integration as a certain kind of procedure based on adding and multiplying that are more natural in single-variable contexts. These include finding the mean and variance of a distribution ($\frac{\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx}{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}$ and $\frac{\int_{a}^{b}x^2f(x)dx}{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}$ respectively) and finding the total mass or charge of a rod given a density function ($\int_{a}^{b}\lambda dr$).

Mean and variance carry over to multivariate probability distributions by multiple integrals, so they are not specific to the single-variable setting. And unless there are more than 1 or 2 lectures on probability in a course, the idea that probability can be expressed by integrals is hard to wrap your head around -- once you are used to it you may forget how strange it can seem initially. Applications of integration to geometry or physical measurements are simpler to motivate in a limited amount of time than the way integrals arise in probability. This is based on my experience teaching.

Upon thinking about this more, I realized that, maybe, many of these applications of integration taught in single-variable calculus can more effectively be taught in multivariable calculus without much issue. The people who would need to know the volumes of solids of revolutions and work done by a fluid are typically physicists and engineers, who will take multivariable calculus eventually.

I don't understand why presenting this material for the first time in multivariable calculus would be more effective. The point of presenting varied applications of single-variable integrals beyond the particular problem of determining areas is to convey the flexibility of integration as soon as possible.  Only using integrals to determine areas in calculus would lead to a limited view of what can be done with integration in single-variable calculus.

A key learning outcome in most Calculus II courses is for students to understand

how to calculate area by integrating distance, and

how to calculate volume by integrating area.


The disk and shell methods are in service of learning outcome (2).
(Edit: slightly rephrased the conditions above to avoid misinterpretation addressed in Xander's answer)
Additionally, I would expect that -- taught properly to students with full knowledge of the prerequisites -- the disk and shell methods would be conceptually easier than making the jump straight into triple integrals.
I realize that someone with full knowledge of these things may find triple integrals easier to think about, but jumping to the most general method typically throws learners for a loop.
Reminds me of a time back when I was teaching, when another teacher wanted to introduce students to differential equations using the terminology "kernel of a linear operator," building up the definitions of "linear operator" and "kernel" instead of going through some concrete computational examples. You can imagine how that went... ;) The "kernel of a linear operator" idea definitely simplifies things in hindsight once you already have a zoo of examples to compress into this idea, but if you don't have that zoo to begin with, then it's pretty hard to understand. In this sense, the disk and shell methods help add to the zoo of concrete examples that are compressed into the idea of integrals in higher-dimensional space.

(+1) Nice answer! I especially like the "kernel of a linear operator" story, as I've seen variations of this approach (in other specific situations) both in others and unfortunately sometimes (viewed in retrospect) with what I've done, although I don't think I've ever gone off the deep end as far what you've described in your example for introducing ODE's to, I presume, calculus-level students.

I'm very skeptical of using a statement like "integrating distance produces an area." If $f(x)$ is a distance that depends on a length $x$, then $\int f(x) dx$ does produce an area... but the summary that "integrating distance produces an area" has forgotten the critical $dx$ entirely. Isn't it better to say that the entire expression $f(x) dx$ is an (infinitesimal) area, and then explain the much simpler fact that integration preserves the units of the thing you are integrating because integration is a sum? Similarly, integrating $v(t) dt$ gives distance because $v(t) dt$ is a distance?

I disagree slightly with the assertion that key outcomes in the class are teaching students that integrating distance gives area, and integrating area gives volume.  While these are important facts which are generally taught in an introductory single-variable calculus class in the US, they are subordinate to a larger theme, i.e. that integrals represent the accumulation of infinitesimal change.

When definite integrals are first introduced, it is usually done as an area under a curve.  An interval in the domain of some function $f$ is partitioned into small intervals of length $\Delta x_j$, and the value of the function on each of these intervals is approximated by $f(x_j^*)$.  This gives an approximation of the area under the function by rectangles with areas $f(x_j^*) \Delta x_j$.  Add up all of these areas, then take a limit to get the exact area.  The big idea is to add up infinitesimal changes in area (these tiny rectangles).
In a single variable environment, the general problem of computing volume is not really possible, but volumes of rotation can be worked with, because they allow for reasonable decompositions.  For example, using cross-sections, partition the domain into intervals of length $\Delta x_j$, then approximate the volume on that interval by a cylinder of width $\Delta x_j$ and radius $f(x_j^*)$.  The total volume is then approximated by summing the volumes of these cylinders.  The big idea is to add up infinitesimal changes in volume (the tiny cylinders).
Work is measure of how a force acts on an object as it moves through space.  At each point in space, the force acts in an infinitesimal manner, and those little infinitesimal forces get added up over the path of the particle.  On an interval of length $\Delta x_j$, a force $F$ will do approximately $F(x_j^*) \Delta x_j$ units of work (e.g. Newton-meters) as the object moves from one end of that little interval to the other.  The big idea is that all of those infinitesimal bits of work can be added up to obtain the total work.
Arc length is an integral!  Suppose that a particle is traveling along $f$ (i.e. the particle's position in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $(t, f(t))$.  Over an increment of time $\Delta t_j$, the particle moves a distance of $\sqrt{\Delta t_j^2 + \Delta y_j}$, where $\Delta y_j = f(t_{j+1}) - f(t_j)$.  By the mean value theorem, there is some $t_j^*$ such that $f'(t_j^*) = \Delta y_j/\Delta t_j$.  Thus the distance a particle moves per some increment of time can be written as $\sqrt{\Delta t_j^2 + f'(t_j^*)^2\Delta t_j^2}$.  The big idea is that each of these little infinitesimal lengths can be added together to obtain the total length (note, here that $\Delta t_j$ has length units, and $f'(t_j^*)$ is a ratio of lengths in this construction, and is unitless).

In each case, it is important to note that both the function being integrated and the increment have units—that is, but $f(x_j^*)$ and $\Delta x_j$ are unitfull (as opposed to unitless), and the big idea is to see how adding up an infinite number of infinitesimal increments can give a meaningful result, particularly if you are careful of keeping track of the units as you go.

integrals represent the accumulation of infinitesimal change. It is a very good (I would say "almost perfect") way to put it. Do you know of any modern calculus textbook that would have these exact words in print?

@fedja No.  And it is one of my frustrations with the kinds of books that get published for introductory calculus classes. :/

@fedja Modern books are mostly scared of the word "infinitesimal", for reasons that are really quite unclear to me; possibly they're written by people who have heard just a bit, but not quite enough, about the foundations of analysis. This leads to the absurdity of teaching of a subject that is literally "infinitesimal calculus" without ever explicitly mentioning the subject's central concept.

I honestly think there are applications of integrals that still require us students to think about integration in terms of accumulating infinitesimal change but are more naturally suited for a single-variable context. An example would be calculating the mean and variance of a distribution (which can be done by $\frac{\int_{a}^{b}xf(x)dx}{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}$ and $\frac{\int_{a}^{b}x^2f(x)dx}{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}$ respectively).

@Heisenberg2010  Those are often taught, too. I tend not to teach very many applications, as they usually come at the end of the semester, but I do teach these. I didn't add them to my post, as they are a little more complicated to describe.

Thank you for this answer; I agree and would go further to say that any claim that integrating area gives volume is simply wrong. In fact $\pi r^2 dx$, the thing that is integrated most often in the volumes of revolution lessons, is a volume, so integrating $\pi r^2 dx$ is integrating volume to get volume, and this key idea is the whole theme of the "applications of integrals" chapter.

@ChrisCunningham I'm not quite sure that I agree with your assertion that volume is being integrated to get volume.  In your example, the integrand (the thing being integrated) is $\pi r^2$ (an area). But the $\mathrm{d}x$ is an infinitesimal vestige of the $\Delta x$ from a Riemann sum approximation, so it, too carries units (of length, in this case).

@XanderHenderson I really want to be able to tell my students that integrating means putting together or adding, which is why we use a big S for the symbol. Addition maintains units, so we add together tiny volumes to get the entire volume. To me, it seems unnecessarily complicated to say "I am integrating $\pi r^2$ which is an area, but this integral is with respect to $x$. We multiply the units of $\pi r^2$ with the units of the integral, transforming area into volume." Why not instead say "I am integrating $\pi r^2 dx$, which is a tiny volume. The result is of course also a volume." ?

In order for students to get a feel for where integrals might show up in future science (and math) courses, it's important that they gain some hands-on experience with setting up integrals via slicing and then taking a limit as the slices get thinner, and there aren't a lot of good candidates for simple problems to do this with. An alternative (which I believe is not in Calculus BC but which I have taught in Calc 2) is computing total work performed in an operation, but this is more abstract and difficult to motivate to students who don't have enough physics.
Volumes of solids of revolution have the advantage of being interesting and easy to visualize, and, as you say, the disadvantage that they are a bit artificial and the students will soon learn a technique for volumes of all solids (and also, as you say, many students memorize them, although you can subvert this and force them to learn the slicing technique by sufficiently diversifying the shapes you ask them to compute volumes of).
One last remark: to prove that integrals over regions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be computed by taking an iterated integral requires mastery of the slicing technique -- so although ultimately triple integrals are the best way to approach the problem, they're putting the cart before the horse in terms of teaching why we're doing what we're doing.

Have you ever noticed that many of the applications of the integral in Calculus 2 - volumes and surface areas of solids of revolution, work, fluid pressure on a submerged plate- are exactly the types of problems encountered with steam engines?  There is a long and convoluted history of calculus instruction in this country.  "Related rates" for example was created by a calculus instructor to illustrate derivatives as rates of change.  The proper terminology for concave up and concave down is "convex" and "concave" respectively.  A critical point at which a function has a local maximum is an argmax of the function.    But such is twentieth century terminology - i.e. not used to study steam engines.
Before Sputnik and the NDEA in 58 or 59, the purpose of calculus instruction at liberal arts institutions was primarily to justify and develop exponentials, logarithms, and exponential growth and decay. The NDEA in part - and a critical shortage of mathematicians in the workforce - transformed all calculus instruction to have an engineering focus. That is the calculus everyone still teaches today.

Are you suggesting that, e.g., related rates is not important to today's technology? If so, machine learning would like to have a word with you ;)

I can't understand what point you're trying to make. Are you claiming the NDEA transformed calculus instruction, in the 1950s, to be all about stuff useful for steam engines?

For those reading the answer who are unfamiliar with the abbreviation used in paragraph 2, NDEA is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Defense_Education_Act
